# Pandas Dataframe Comparisons

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am learning Pandas dataframes for a project and having trouble understanding some of the operators and how I can use them.  In one case, I have one dataframe for production data and another for targets.  I can get the items in the production data that met the targets and those that didn't using:

```
good = prod['A'][prod['A'] >= target['A']]
bad = prod['A'][prod['A'] < target['A']]
```

and it works well.  But in some cases, I have an upper and lower target, which is where I am getting stuck.  I need to find the values that are above the upper target, the values below the lower target and the values that were in between and get 3 separate dataframes.  I tried what seemed obvious working with normal lists:

```
aboveTargetA = prod['A'][prod['A'] >= targetA['A']]
belowTargetB = prod['A'][prod['A'] <= targetB['A']]
betweenTargets = prod[[col for index, col in df.iterrows() if col not in aboveTargetA and col not in belowTargetB]]
```

I'm not sure how I should be doing it with these dataframes and generators as I have never worked with them before.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for the comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do boolean indexing with multiple conditions:

```
prod['A'][(prod['A'] < targetA['A']) & (prod['A'] > targetB['A'])]
```

See also http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#boolean-indexing